# Where do I find logs for containerized Flask server?

Tags: docker, flask

I'm getting status code 500 on my Dockerized Flask server.
I bashed into the container to check the logs:

`docker exec -ti container_name /bin/bash`

in `/var/log` I found:

```
root@b80b0c02fd18:/var/log# ls -al
total 224
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Oct 13 21:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Oct 12 07:00 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9052 Oct 20 20:50 alternatives.log
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Oct 20 20:49 apt
-rw-rw---- 1 root utmp      0 Oct 12 07:00 btmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 164661 Oct 20 20:50 dpkg.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3232 Oct 12 07:00 faillog
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp  29492 Oct 12 07:00 lastlog
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp      0 Oct 12 07:00 wtmp
```

I couldn't `cat` or `nano` the files `faillog` nor `lastlog` so I don't know if the files
are relevant.

Where do I find access log or error log for containerized Flask server ?

Comment: That's going to be a function of your application.  When you run it outside of Docker, where does it write its logs?  Can you include your Dockerfile and other information required for a [mcve]?

Comment: I thought there's a well known default location where all logs are in Flask container.

Comment: @DavidMaze When you run Flask server off Docker you would find logs in `/var/log` or sometimes in `/var/www`

Comment: Please show the code that causes it to write out log files to some specific location.  There's no particular magic in Docker that would cause logs to go to a specific place without configuring it.

Answer (score 0):

`docker logs <your container_name>` to see the logs of the container

You can also find the logs for the flask app at `/var/log/daemon.log`

Comment: I know about `docker logs ...` but that output just gives me a request that resulted in 500 but it doesn't give me any clue as to why. What's the cause. Hence I wanted to dig deeper in logs.

Comment: I've got no `daemon.log` file in that location.

Comment: Check this /var/lib/docker/containers/[container-id]/[container-id]-json.log.

Comment: I'm presuming you mean within my local filesystem. I've got no such path. I've got `/var/lib/docker/snap/livepatch/..`